# JS script for airplane plotting simple as a hell

Tags: open-source, javascript, google-maps, plotting

I want to have my very own Flightradar24 / FlightAware.com / VirtualRadar in my browser, but with the functionality limited to plotting points at Google Map / Bing Map / Leaf.js / Apple Maps / whatever. Nothing more.

In other words, I need a piece of code that I will be able to feed with data (an array of three values):

- latitude (i.e. `50.534`)
- longitude (i.e. `18.246`)
- description (i.e. `MFLCN`)

[image]

And that script will:

- plot all the points on map
- register itself or allow me to register an *OnClick* callback for each of the points.

The plotted elements must be objects, not direct drawings. Meaning that if I run the plotting method again, it will update location of existing objects on the map, instead of plotting their new copies -- just as in Flightradar24 / FlightAware.com / Virtual Radar and many more plane-tracking, car-tracking or whatever-tracking websites.

Is there anything ready out-of-the box that someone could recommend? Or should I just sit down and write it myself in Leaf.js, reinveting the wheel again? Thank you!

Comment: What makes you think this is simple?

Comment: I have some coding experience and I see plotting X,Y array on Google Maps using Leaflet.js, D3,js etc. a quite very simple task. What makes you think this is not simple? Let me underline once more that the sole purpose for this question is to not reinvent the wheel again and not craft my own invention, if something like that already exists. Otherwise this is doable in a couple of hours, if not less.